Javascript touch event on mobile not working
When adding a touchstart and touchend event listener to my window or my document it just doesnt work when touching or swiping the screen on mobile

document.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
});


document.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
});

I have tried to put the event on multiple elements in my project, also I have tried using hammerjs and the events work fine on desktop but not on mobile and for mobile i have used both microsoft edge and google.
